# Como hacer un json array :$ en swift 3?

Tags: json, array, swift3

hola que tal necesito ayuda, no se como hacer un `JsonArray` en swift 3, lo unico que eh conseguido es hacer esto:

```
{ "Etiqueta":"valor", "":"", "":"" }
```

y lo que necesito hacer es esto:

```
[
   {
      "Etiqueta":"valor",
      "Etiqueta":"valor",
      "Etiqueta":"valor"
   },
   {
      "Etiqueta":"valor",
      "Etiqueta":"valor",
      "Etiqueta":"valor"
   }
]
```

el código que utilizo para crear el `json` es este:

```
    var json = [String : AnyObject]()
    var arrayFinish = [String: AnyObject]()

    json["idProducto"] = String(celda) as AnyObject
    json["comentario"] = tfComentario.text! as AnyObject
    json["TipoUnidad"] = pickerselected as String as AnyObject
    json["Cantidad"] = cantidad as String as AnyObject
    json["Medida"] = medidas as String as AnyObject
    json["telefono"] = telefono as String as AnyObject

    arrayFinish["productos"]?.add(json)
```

y lo único que consigo es `[:]` así se muestra en el `log`

alguien que me ayude por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lo estás añadiendo bien, debes darle el array ya completo.

```
    var arrayProductos = [[String : AnyObject]]()
    var json = [String : AnyObject]()
    var arrayFinish = [String: AnyObject]()

    json["idProducto"] = String(celda) as AnyObject
    json["comentario"] = tfComentario.text! as AnyObject
    json["TipoUnidad"] = pickerselected as String as AnyObject
    json["Cantidad"] = cantidad as String as AnyObject
    json["Medida"] = medidas as String as AnyObject
    json["telefono"] = telefono as String as AnyObject

    arrayProductos.append(json)

    arrayFinish["productos"] = arrayProductos as AnyObject
```

Y aunque lo estés llamando json, en realidad estás trabajando con diccionarios. Si quisieras enviarlo a una API tendrías que usar [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization)